# SAS Point counts for grid cells

Tags: sas, grid, cluster-analysis

I am working on a class project and hitting a wall. The idea seems simple enough, but I cannot seem to get started. We are given a dataset that contains 300 x and y data points. After loading the data into SAS and running a scatter plot on the data, we are instructed to wire SAS code to count each grid cell's points. Like (1,1) has 5 data points. The end product should be a table with the counts that kind of looks like:

```
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,

0, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 

1, 3, 0, 5, 9, 0, 2,
```

Sorry I am not cool enough to post images.

I am confident this is a simple request, but I am short of figuring out the answer. I have run through variations of COUNT, FREQ, and TABULATE. Your assistance is much appreciated.

Comment: What are the possible values that the X and Y variables can contain?

Comment: @Tom - X and y values are between 0 and 7 and are not whole numbers, i.e., a value could be 1.0982532. That is the issue I am having with the TABULATE call. The results are a 1 for every point where I want quadrant 1,1 to show that 5 points exist.

Comment: If you use a format to collapse the values into categories then procs like FREQ or TABLUALTE will summarize by the formatted value.  Try `format x y 1.;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reporting purposes:

- `TABULATE` use `X` and `Y` as `CLASS` variables.  You will be able to table the `x` and `y` combination (i.e. coordinate) counts.
- `REPORT` use `Y` as an `ACROSS` variable.

For data purposes:

- `FREQ` followed by `TRANSPOSE`.  However the resultant data form is not very useful.

Example:

```
data have;
  call streaminit(2020115);
  do _n_ = 1 to 300;
    x = rand('integer',0,5);
    y = rand('integer',0,5);
    output;
  end;
run;

ods html file='tabulate.html';

proc tabulate data=have;
  class x y;
  table x,y / nocellmerge;
run;

proc report data=have;
  columns x y;
  define x / group;
  define y / across;
run;

proc freq noprint data=have;
  table x * y / out=counts(keep=x y count);
run;

proc transpose data=counts out=wider_not_better(drop=_name_ _label_) prefix=y_count_for_;
  by x;
  id y;
  var count;
  format _0 _1 _2 _3 _4 _5 6.;
run;

proc print data=wider_not_better;
run;

ods html close;
```

Will produce output such as

[image]
[image]

[image]